# Load Data from Scrolling to bottom last cell in UICollectionView Calling API with Activity Indicator (Swift4)

Tags: swift4, swift4.2, swift5

I am using UICollectionView in my project. I am calling API to load data in that CollectionView. and I want to load more data when scrolling down to the bottom of UICollectionView with bottom Activity Indicator. My API is in Pagination. Simple Example it is like Soficalmedia App Scrolling. Facebook, Instagram. Scroll down to load Previous data. Can you anyone help me to do this in an efficient way.

I tried a code but it is not working properly: from URl: [Load More data on Scroll Demand on CollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905253/load-more-data-on-scroll-demand-on-collectionview)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
if indexPath.row == numberofitem.count - 1 {  //numberofitem count
    updateNextSet()
}}

func updateNextSet(){
print("On Completetion")
//requests another set of data (20 more items) from the server.
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: collectionView.reloadData)
 }
```

Comment: are you making next page api call in your updateNextSet() function???

Comment: Yes,  updateNextSet() API will Call, but only when we are at last cell of CollectionView. and At bottom loader should be appear to load new data .